# Morphological operation for separating overlap objects

Tags: matlab, image-processing, overlapping

In Matlab, I would like to use erosion to separate two (or multiple) overlap convex shape objects. I have used different structuring elements, but after a number of erosion I lose the original shape of the objects (their circular shape).
Here is the code:

```
imgbw = ~imread('img_ellipse.tif'); 
se = strel('disk',1);
img = imgbw;
figure
for i=0:15              
  img = imerode(img,se,'same');
  if mod(i,5)==0
      subplot(1,4,i/5+1), imshow(img);
  end
end
```

Is there any particular approach for erosion emphasizing on shrinking the narrow parts of the objects? Please can anyone help me?

Comment: After separating into separate parts, you need to enumerate the parts, and then grow the enumeration or label over the eroded areas.  That will allow you to restore the original shape and still provide the separation.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what the image looks like?  Have you tried an opening filter?  It is an erosion then dilation chained together.  It allows the separation of objects connected in a minimal way while roughly preserving the shape of the overall objects.  Also, building on what Jim said, check the `imreconstruct` command. It essentially does the second part of what he is talking about. http://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imreconstruct.html

Comment: It is also possible to use watershed on the distance map of the image to separate two overlapping objects.